# create n-parent process with different children process in c

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to write a c program that create N-parent process with their children, but what happens instead is that I create several child processes that are linked to a parent. I need help changing the code to create as many parents as children. In addition, the program will await all child processes. Thanks for your help! Below u see my code that which certainly needs to be changed.

```
int main(void)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int i, N=0;
  scanf("%d", &N);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  pid = fork();
  switch(pid) {
   case -1:
   fprintf(stderr,"fork failed");
   exit (1);

   case 0:
    printf("I am the child with pid = %d\n",getpid());
    printf("My parent has pid = %d\n", getppid());
    sleep (20);
    exit(0);

   default:
    wait (0);
   }
 }
 return 0; 

}
```

Comment: I would urge all the people giving down votes to also give the reason for doing so that the person asking can work on them and ask a better/improved question next time. Downvote doesn't really help with an explanation.

Comment: This question shows no research effort. "Here's the code that needs to be changed" sounds more like "write code for me" than a question. It's also unclear (what is "N-parent process" supposed to mean?).

Comment: With the exception of the init process (with pid 0) every process is a child process of some other process and every child process becomes a parent process when it creates new children. So if want your child processes to become parents, your children must call `fork()`. But I don't see what's the point of this exercise.

Comment: @Pablo can u give me a example? I can't figure it out.

Comment: An example about what?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing is the basic understanding of parent and child processes. I will try to help with that and I am sure you will be able to correct your program yourself.

Except "init" process every process has a parent. You want to create N parent process but those N processes will have to have a parent until they are not "init" process and also you can not have more than one "init" process.

In your case "main" should be the parent, of your N parent processes(which are nothing but the children of "main" process) and then these N parent processes can have their children processes.

I hope this information helps. Happy Coding :)